# Active Cell Value other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Asking if someone can correct this formula:

I have Workbook `Try1` and `Try2` and I want to get the value on an active cell of `Try1` to specific range in `Try2`.

I have this code:

```
Range("K1") = Workbooks("Try1").Sheets("Try").ActiveCell.Value
```

Comment: assuming activecell is range("A1")  (change the range 
 if needed). I think to pass a value from a 
 workbook to another in VBA you can write something like this: Workbooks("Try2").Sheets("Try").Range("K1").value = Workbooks("Try1").Sheets("Try").range("A1").value

Comment: Yeah that should be the logic, but what I'm trying to do is instead of using a fix Range, im doing it dynamically since im incorporating it to a Loop where in it changes the activecell

Comment: using active cell is not dynamic, just bad practice. if you want to iterate through cells you can use a for loop for example .cell(i,1).value or .range("A" & i). or create a range object, and use "for each" to iterate through  each cell in range created.

Comment: okay, I'll try that, thanks for the advise. Ill notify if once good.